# Remove option (recompile) from code

Tags: sql-server, parameter-passing

I have these queries…

```
declare @month as int = 9
Select c1,c2
From table
Where datepart (m, InserDate) = @month
```

It takes 55 minutes to run.

```
declare @month as int = 9
Select c1,c2
From table
Where datepart (m, InserDate) = @month
option (recompile)
```

Takes 9 seconds.

```
declare @month as int = 9
Select c1,c2
From table
Where datepart (m, InserDate) = 9
```

Take 7 seconds.

```
Select c1,c2
From table
Where datepart (m, InserDate) = 9
```

Takes 5 seconds

My question is, how can I make the first code to run in seconds without using “option (recompile)”

Ad info:
The actual code is:

```
DECLARE @Mon int = DATEPART(m, DATEADD(m, -1, getdate()))
DECLARE @Yr int = DATEPART(yyyy, DATEADD(m, -1, getdate()))
```

...

```
WHERE   
     DATEPART(m, cc.insertdate) = @Mon
     AND DATEPART(yyyy, cc.insertdate) = @Yr
```

The values for InsertDate are from: 2008-07-16 02:29:48.203 to 2016-10-24 07:06:58.337

And, as you can see I am only retrieving “last month” data...
Is option(recompile) really necessary? Why sql is not smart enough?

Comment: You'd better explain why you don't want to use `option(recompile)`.

Comment: If all of the `InserDate` values occupy a single year, computing `[start date, end date)` and using those for a comparison could do a lot better then extracting the month from the column. Don't know if that fits your data though.

Comment: Did you try the new answer I gave on your question?

Comment: @TT. worked like a charm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have a suitable (covering) index on the `insert_date` field, you could write something like the following:

```
DECLARE @Mon int = DATEPART(m, DATEADD(m, -1, getdate()));
DECLARE @Yr int = DATEPART(yyyy, DATEADD(m, -1, getdate()));

SELECT
    c1,
    c2
FROM
    your_table
WHERE
    insert_date>=DATEFROMPARTS(@Yr,@Mon,1) AND
    insert_date<DATEADD(MONTH,1,DATEFROMPARTS(@Yr,@Mon,1));
```

---

The way you have the query written in your question does not allow for using an index on the `insert_date` field. This is because you are applying a function to it, and only then do the comparison.